# DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate binding looks in main Data Context

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, data-binding

Something obvious, but I'm stuck here..

I want to display DataGrid inside DataGrid, here is XAML:

```
<sdk:DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding RNPPayPlanLanes}" 
    RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="From region" Binding="{Binding FromRegionKey, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="To region" Binding="{Binding ToRegionKey, Mode=TwoWay}" />        
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    <sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <sdk:DataGrid 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                ItemsSource="{Binding RNPPayPlanLaneDistances}">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="UpToDistance" Binding="{Binding UpToDistance, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="PayPerDistanceUnitAmount" Binding="{Binding PayPerDistanceUnitAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" />                    
                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

MyViewModel contains collection of `RNPPayPlanLane` objects, I see them bound properly.

Pseudocode of VM:

```
class MyViewModel
{
public List<RNPPayPlanLane> RNPPayPlanLanes { get; set; }
}

class RNPPayPlanLane
{
public List<RNPPayPlanLaneDistance> RNPPayPlanLaneDistances { get; set; }
}

class RNPPayPlanLaneDistance {}
```

`RNPPayPlanLane` has collection property 'RNPPayPlanLaneDistances' which I'm trying to use for nested grid. This doesn't work. I get error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error:
>   'RNPPayPlanLaneDistances' property not found on 'MyViewModel'

So, it is not binding to "current item", it is trying to bind to my main DataContext. Why? And what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I use telerik's hierarchical grid. I need to define a hierarchy, didn't use RowDetailsTemplate but your error says the property is missing so,

As I understand

Each **LanesData** has one **RNPPayPlanLane** 1-1

Each **RNPPayPlanLane** has many **RNPPayPlanLaneDistances** 1-N (master-detail)

So as if it should be like that,

```
       ItemsSource="{Binding RNPPayPlanLane.RNPPayPlanLaneDistances}">
```

Comment: I added more code. No it's not like you describe. I expected RNPPayPlanLaneDistances to be a property, but error clearly says that nested grid looks into VM (main DataContext, not on current item)

Comment: It looks you are right. It should firstly look own datacontext.

Comment: For telerik it works as expected http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radgridview-row-details-template.html